# Strange issue with Zend_Validate_Identical?

Tags: zend-form, zend-validate, zend-framework

I had write the following code in my Zend Form:

```
    $newpassword = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('newpassword');
    $newpassword->setLabel("Enter your New Password :")
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator(
                     'NotEmpty',
                      TRUE,
                      array('messages' => array(
                              'isEmpty' => 'Please enter new password.'
                                               )
                           )
                     )
               ->addValidator(
                    'Alnum',
                     TRUE,
                     array('messages' => array(
                                 'alnumInvalid' => 'Please enter a valid new password.',
                                 'notAlnum' => 'Please enter a valid new password.',
                                 'alnumStringEmpty' => 'Please enter a valid new password.'
                                              )
                          )
                          )
               ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(4, 25))
               ->getValidator('StringLength')->setMessage("Should be 4-25 characters long.");


    $retypepassword = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('retypepassword');
    $retypepassword->setLabel("Retype-Password :")
                   ->setRequired(true)
                   ->addFilter('StripTags')
                   ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                   ->addValidator(
                        'NotEmpty',
                        TRUE,
                        array('messages' => array(
                                         'isEmpty' => 'Please enter confirm password.'
                                                 )
                             )
                       )
                    ->addValidator(
                         new Zend_Validate_Identical('newpassword'),
                         TRUE,
                         array('messages' => array(
 'notSame' => 'New password and confirm password are not matching. They must be same.',
 'missingToken' => 'New password and confirm password are not matching. They must be same.'
                                                  )
                                           )
                                  )
              ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(4, 25))
              ->getValidator('StringLength')->setMessage("Should be 4-25 characters long.");
```

As you can see that I had override the error messages for **Zend_Validate_Identical** i.e. for *notSame* and *missignToken*, but still the form is showing the default error message i.e. *"The two given tokens do not match"*

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$options` parameter to `Zend_Form_Element::addValidator` gets ignored completely if you pass it a validator object (which you're doing by passing `new Zend_Validate_Identical`).

Instead, you want to do something closer to the way you've added your other validators:

```
$this->addValidator(
    'Identical',
    TRUE,
    array('token' => 'newpassword',
          'messages' => array(
              'notSame' => 'New password and confirm password are not matching. They must be same.',
              'missingToken' => 'New password and confirm password are not matching. They must be same.'
          )
    )
);
```